# How do you turn on and off a bots reactions?

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I've been working on a bot (using js) that reacts to every message sent and I've been trying to give it on and off commands. Is there a way to have on and off commands when it comes to reactions from bots?
This is what I have:

top:

```
var emojissetting = 0
```

on / off (tried with changing the variable to 0 or 1):

```
if (msg === prefix + 'START'){
emojisetting = 1;
message.channel.send("Snoopy is now reading the chat. :book:");
}

if (msg === prefix + 'STOP'){
    emojisetting = 0;
    message.channel.send("Snoopy has stopped reading the chat. :blue_book:");
}
```

bottom:

```
bot.on('message', message => {

    if(emojisetting = 0){
        if (message) {
            return;
          }
    }
    if(emojisetting = 1){
            if (message) {
              emojirandom = emojisnop[Math.floor(Math.random() * emojisnop.length)]
                message.react(emojirandom)
            }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if your bot is going to run in more than one server, it's probably gonna get API banned because you would exceed the rate-limit of adding reactions to messages, if I remember correctly the limit is probably 1 reaction every 0.25 seconds.

Anyway, what you did is correct but it will only work for one server, because 'emojisetting' is a global variable of the bot. You could create an array of objects to store that setting for each server, for example:

```
emojisettings = [
    {
        guildID = 5365657435245;
        enabled = true;
    }

        guildID = 3543265356345;
        enabled = false;
    }
]
```

In this example we stored two settings for two different servers, identified by their IDs. Also we used true and false instead of 0/1 because it's more ideal and easy to handle.

Then we will need to let users handle this setting with a command, for example:

```js
if (msg === prefix + 'START' || msg === prefix + 'STOP'){
    //Define if enabling or not the bot 
    let enabling = true;
    if(msg === prefix + 'STOP') enabling = false;

    //Let's get the guild ID from the msg
    let guildID = msg.guild.ID;
    //Find the corresponding object in the array of the settings
    let index = emojisettings.findIndex(element => element.guildID === guildID);

    //If we found the guild setting
    if(index >-1){
       emojisettings[index].enabled = enabling;
    }
    //If not found that means the guild isn't stored in the array, so we need to create a new object for it
    else{
        emojisettings = emojisettings.push({guildID = msg.guild.ID, enabled = enabling});
    }
    //Reply to the message
    if(enabling) message.channel.send("Snoopy is now reading the chat. :book:");
    else message.channel.send("Snoopy is not reading the chat. :book:");
}
```

Keep in mind that this settings will be lost if the bot gets stopped, so if the bot stops running all this settings will be lost, so if you want to keep this setting forever you will need a database, I would suggest you mongoDB, but there are many others and if your bot is not in many servers you can even use a simple json file even if not optimal and risky sometimes.

After that we can simply check if the setting is enabled and if so react to the message:

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
        //Check if message was received in a server and not in DMs
        if(message.channel.type !== 'text') return;

        //Check if the setting is enabled for the server where you received the message
        let enabled = emojisettings.find(element => element.guildID === message.guild.ID).enabled;

        //If setting is enabled, react to the message
        if (enabled) {
                  emojirandom = emojisnop[Math.floor(Math.random() * emojisnop.length)]
                    message.react(emojirandom)
                }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One question about it is if my bot was added to discord servers that I don't have the id to how do I set up the emojisettings guild id?

Comment: This is done here: `emojisettings = emojisettings.push({guildID = msg.guild.ID, enabled = enabling});`
Feel free to upvote / accept my answer if it helped ya

Comment: Alrighty. Another thing I'm trying to learn how to code and I'm a little confused on where to put the emojisettings array. Any help on that?

Comment: Seen that it has to be used anywhere in your bot, you should declare it globally, so at the beginning of your code usually